# Identify the Pico core at runtime

Tags: c, pi-pico

Using the C/C++ Pico SDK, how can I find out which core my code is running on?

(Specifically, I'd like to use lwIP's `LWIP_ASSERT_CORE_LOCKED`, which requires a thread or core identifier to determine whether it holds the right locks.)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why I didn't find it the last time around, but there's `get_core_num()` in [`pico_platform`](https://raspberrypi.github.io/pico-sdk-doxygen/group__pico__platform.html#ga974b4945ae0ac8892717cb5f05e83c53).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).